# Need help saving plant!

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, chinese-evergreen

I don't know exactly what kind of plant I have someone suggested it might be a Chinese evergreen? I got it as a gift last year when I was sick in the hospital. Although I've been watering it about every 3 weeks and giving it partial sunlight every day it's just not thriving or healthy as it should be.

I think it's dying!

[image]

It's in a pot that drains, haven't changed anything about it since I've had it. Please help me save my plant?

Answer (score 2):

It is a Chinese evergreen, botanical name *Aglaonema* and yes, it's in poor condition. These plants do not like any direct sun - yours appears to have some pink variegation, so it will appreciate bright daylight, but no sun - non variegated types will grow well in relatively darker situations.

The photo is not of sufficiently good quality to magnify in order to examine the leaves more closely to determine whether there is a pest or disease problem with the plant - you could examine the leaves and stems with a magnifying glass to see if it has anything such as spider mite which might be causing a problem.

I note you have the plant sitting in an outer container, and you say you water about every three weeks - it may be  your watering regime needs changing. As with most plants, when the surface of the potting soil feels dry to the touch, but not so dry it's shrunken from the sides of the pot, a thorough watering should be done, allowing any excess to drain away freely from the base. Any outer pot or tray should be emptied 30 minutes after watering to ensure the plant is not left sitting in water.

Find a more suitable spot for it so that it does not receive sun, away from any heat sources, and water ongoing as described. The soil currently looks like it might be damp - if it is, wait till the surface has dried out a bit before watering again. You can also try giving it a feed with something like Baby Bio houseplant food, intended for use on foliage plants, but don't apply more often than once a fortnight or so, or according to the instructions on whatever product you use. Hopefully, it may recover. Further info on these plants and their care here [How to Grow Chinese Evergreen Indoors](https://www.thespruce.com/grow-aglaonema-houseplants-1902734).

Answer (score 0):

Aglaonema, (Chinese evergreen ); However the cause of the problem is not apparent. I have had them and they were relatively hardy. An internet search may give you an answer.